# React Native iOS build failed as operation not permitted

Tags: ios, react-native

when I try to build the ios app with

react-native run-ios

I receive

```
error: unable to open output file '.../ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/double-conversion.o': 'Operation not permitted'
1 error generated.
```

The environment

MacBook Pro Mojave 10.14.5

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error on mac, it is because you system is not allowing react native to read or write some files.

**Please try this one**

```
sudo react-native run-ios
```

Hope so it will help

Comment: thnx I have tried sudo but still have problem with permission denied
couldn't read dependency graph from '..../ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/dgph': Permission denied